# RequestLibrary module not found

Tags: robotframework

I need to use the RequestsLibrary library and when I import it:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   SeleniumLibrary
Library   RequestsLibrary
```

I get an error module not found. When I run `pipenv graph` I can clearly see it's installed:

```
(marek) bash-3.2$ pipenv graph
robotframework-requests==0.5.0
- requests [required: Any, installed: 2.22.0]
- certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2019.6.16]
- chardet [required: >=3.0.2,<3.1.0, installed: 3.0.4]
- idna [required: >=2.5,<2.9, installed: 2.8]
- urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.26,!=1.25.1,!=1.25.0, installed: 1.25.3]
- robotframework [required: Any, installed: 3.1.2]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: can you please run $ robot --version and tell me the version you get, is it 3.1.2? Can you also check python version?

Comment: Python version is 3.7.x and Robot version is 3.1.2 as shown on the output above.

Comment: please show the full error.

Comment: don't you need requests-oauthlib                      1.2.0 as well?

Answer (score 0):

As turned out the issue was the fact that I installed the library using `pipenv install xyz` and that creates brand new virtual environment prior to library installation. So I basically ended up with a virtual environment within virtual environment and Robot couldn't access it. As soon as I got rid off the extra virtual environment, exited out and ran `pipenv install robotframework-requests` outside of any venv, it ran.